# fopen() not finding file in same directory using php

Tags: php, csv, phpexcel, fopen, xls

I am attempting to use fopen() to allow me to pass values from csv cells to an Oracle 11g Database.

The csv was 'created' when a user uploads an xls via a html form. From there, I converted 'file.xls' to 'file.csv'. Up to this part, I have been successful. However, upon using fopen() [line 33, it is marked in notes], it fails to find the obviously created 'file.csv'. Is my notation wrong for using fopen()?

handler:

```
$allowed =  array('xls');
$filename = $_FILES['uploaded']['name'];
$file = $_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'];
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(in_array($ext,$allowed) ) {

    $inputFileType = 'Excel5';
    $inputFileName = $file;

    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $objPHPExcelReader = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

    $loadedSheetNames = $objPHPExcelReader->getSheetNames();

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcelReader, 'CSV');

    foreach($loadedSheetNames as $sheetIndex => $loadedSheetName) {
            $objWriter->setSheetIndex($sheetIndex);
            $objWriter->save('file'.'.csv');}

    }
    $fopen = fopen('file.csv', 'r'); //**line 33**//
    if($fopen) {
            while (($line = fgetcsv($files)) !== FALSE) {
            $csv_array[] = array_combine(range(1, count($line)), array_values($line));
            }
    }
```

It may be nice to note that I do plan on adding a delete section to delete 'file.csv'. I am only using it to update the database, then it is useless to me. So, if there is a more efficient way than saving it, updating db, deleting it, I would love to know :). Thanks, SO community!

Comment: did you check if your `$objWriter->save()` call is succeeding, or even executing in the first place? Plus, you never bother checking if your upload succeeded in the first place.

Comment: You are correct that my code does not check, however I look in the database and the file is saved successfully.

Comment: Plus, the save call doesn't look right. seems redundant to specify the extension in a second arg. why not just `->save('file.csv')`? Check your server if you have just `file` in there.

Comment: ^^that code does work. Obviously meaning my code was redundant. However, fopen() still doesn't open it. I'll try marty's idea of making the paths absolute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on where `$objWriter->save()` will save the file. If that is the same folder as the input file then it will be your temporary directory (/tmp/ most likely on *nix)
And it is not likely that `open()` will look there by default.

You can avoid these problems my making all paths absolute.

Comment: Yeah, you were right fopen() wasn't looking in the right path. Rookie mistake hehe